# Getting a filtered Maven dependency update list

Tags: maven, dependencies, filtering, updates

I've got a question regarding updating dependencies. Im looking for a project that will lookup Maven (and eventually Gradle as well) dependencies based on my current dependencies and get the critical updates. I dont want to auto update everything, since that might mess up compatibility.

Maven already has `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` which gives you a list of all outdated dependecies. What would be nice is to have something that takes the results of that command and filters all dependencies for critical/security updates.
Has anyone seen something to do that (or know a hidden mvn command) or should I start scripting?

Cheers!

Comment: You'll start scripting, since there isn't (AFAIK) any standardized metadata that explains the purpose of any updates (or intervening updates, since there could be multiple). Even scripting this would be problematic.

Comment: I don't know of a scripting/command line solution, but there are products that can do stuff like this. Nexus comes to mind, but I'm not sure if a paid solution, or even Nexus in general is an option for you.

Comment: Re „_filters all dependencies for critical/security updates_“. The information whether a new artifact version contains criritcal or security updates is a semantic one. It's not an information of (build) management which is Maven's job. Hence, artifacts are solely identified by [coordinates comprising `groupId:artifactId:[packaging:classifier:]version`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) and there's no corresponding POM element. (Though `<description>` could be used for that, but that'd be not a standard one can rely on for every dependency.)

Comment: Agree, there is no standardized way. Just right now Id have to plow through a lot of release notes to do this manually. Hence the question. I will look into Nexus and see if it helps. Thanks for the feeback guys.